# How to overcome Capacitor Initialize error in angular 13.x

Tags: android, angular, capacitor

I am trying to install Capacitor in my angular 13.x project.

## The first step is successfully added:

```
npm install @capacitor/core
npm install @capacitor/cli --save-dev
```

## Facing error when run Capacitor Initialize command.

```
$ npx cap init
[error] Non-interactive shell detected.
        Run the command with --help to see a list of arguments that must be provided.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a non interactive terminal/cmd. Capacitor prompts you for data such as app name, app id and web dir.
But since you are using a non interactive terminal/cmd it can’t prompt you.

Switch to a interactive terminal/cmd or provide all the parameters on npx cap init command

```
npx cap init appName appID --web-dir webDir
```

Comment: How to make non-interactive terminal to  interactive terminal? Now i am using git bash terminal

Comment: You can’t make a non interactive terminal to be interactive. Git terminal is non interactive. You can use interactive terminals such as cmd or powershell on windows, or the terminal app on macOS or Linux.